# What is a good way to share an android service across different activities

Tags: android, android-service

How can I make only one service in an application, and make its constituting activities share it across them? Can I initialize it in first activity, make it public static, and refer to it directly in other activities? Or do I need to create a singleton class of it, and instantiate it in every activity?

Please help me find a way to do this. Thanks

----update-----------

say there's Activity1, Activity2, and Service3

Can I make it like this:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity{
    public static Service3 mserv; 
    onCreate(){
        bindService(new Intent(this, Service3.class))
    }
    ...
}

public class Activity2 extends Activity{
    public Service3 mservice;

    onCreate(){
        mservice = Activity1.mserv;
    }
    ....
}

public Service3 extends Service{
   onCreate(){
    ....
   }

   onBind(){
    ...
   }
}
```

Comment: what is your requirement share some idea,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to speak with service, read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

It should look some thing like that:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourServiceClass.class);
  activity.startService(intent);
```

You service will get `Service.onStartCommand`

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your Service explicitly by calling `startService()`. Then you can either [Bind](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) to it or coummunicate with it via `LocalBroadcastManager`.